# Запретить нажимать кнопку обновления на странице

Tags: javascript, обновление

Есть идеи каким образом можно запретить пользователю нажимать кнопку обновление страницы и в целом выключить кнопку обновления страницы? С F5 уже разобрался, использовал команду *preventDefault()*.
Но как быть с кнопкой обновления? Очень хотелось бы решить данную проблему.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если Вы о кнопке перезагрузки странице в тулбаре браузера, то никак. Это было бы явно не очень приятно, если бы кто-то имел такую возможность.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда ищу обходные пути. Есть ли возможность определить, зафиксировать момент, когда пользователь обновил страницу?

Comment: Зачем вам это вообще?

Comment: Интересно было бы посмотреть как вы разобрались с перезагрузкой на мобилках, где для перезагрузки можно оттянуть экран вниз и отпустить))

Comment: максимум что можно отследить - загрузка и выгрузка страницы

Comment: Понятно, значит буду сам пытаться разобраться без этого запрета. Алексей Шиманский, в интернете видел пару тем на эту проблему, решением было изменить размеры окна или спрятать боковую панель прокрутки страницы.

Comment: @EzioMercer Да я делаю небольшую игру в браузере, основанную на JS, CSS и HTML, и хотел бы исключить возможность обновить страницу, чтобы пользователь не мог сбросить некоторые значения путем обновления страницы, которые он получил во время процесса. Думаю помните меня с прошлого раза, где мы разбирались с проблемой столкновения круга и угла прямоугольника.

Comment: Ну храните данные в localStorage и при загрузке страницы подгружайте свои данные оттуда

Comment: Вот я так и придумал сделать, когда понял, что нельзя запретить обновление страницы.